# Problemas al intentar leer un archivo con Python 3.9.2

Tags: python, python-3.9

Estoy intentando leer un archivo con python 3.9.2 pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/diccionario_Esval.py", line 6, in <module>
    file = f.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 4860328: invalid continuation byte
```

El script que tengo de momento es el siguiente:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

try:
    with open('pass8.txt',mode='rt',encoding='utf-8') as f:
        file = f.read()
        print(file)
except OSError:
    print("No se puede leer")
```

Nota: la lista que se está leyendo y el script se encuentran en la misma ubicación.

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Desktop]
└─$ ls                                                                                              1 ⨯
diccionario_Esval.py  pass8.txt
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Se solucionó agregando un nuevo flag errors con el valor 'ignore' dentro del método open quedando de la siguiente forma.

Script funcionando:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

try:
    with open('pass8.txt',mode='r',encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore') as f:
        file = f.read()
        print(file)
except OSError:
    print("No se puede leer")
```

Ahora es posible leer la lista sin problemas.

Comment: Claramente eso soluciona el error, pero el error en si es que no estas usando el formato adecuado de decodificación y por eso se genera el error. Podrías evitar el parámetro `encoding` y de esta forma puthon usa la codificación de tu S.O., si de igual forma obtienes el error entonces el parámetro `errors` es suficiente, ya que es más fácil eso antes que averiguar la codificación real del archivo o algún carácter